# Connotación de la expresión "no + deber + infinitivo"

Tags: gramática, significado

En la ayuda de un juego aparece la frase:

> son figuras que no deben aparecer alineadas para ganar puntos

En éste, si se alinean 3 o más figuras iguales éstas desaparecen y otorgan puntos en función de la figura. Sin embargo, existen unas figuras especiales que con sólo aparecer en la pantalla ya otorgan puntos.

De la frase anterior deduciría que si estas figuras especiales aparecen alineadas no deberían otorgar puntos. Sin embargo, sí lo hacen en el juego.

La duda es si la expresión "no + deber + infinitivo" implica que "no es necesario que" o implica "no ocurre en el supuesto de que".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Según la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=deber), existen las formas

- Deber + infinitivo, que denota obligación, y
- Deber + de + infinitivo, que denota probabilidad.

Ejemplos:

> ***Aquí debe haber al menos cien personas*** (como puede decir el que está preparando un grupo de extras para una escena en una película, obligando a que en dicha escena haya ese número de extras).
>
> ***Aquí debe de haber al menos cien personas*** (como puede decir el que llega a un sitio y se topa con una manifestación, sorprendido por el evento inesperado y contando más o menos a las mismas).

No importa que la expresión vaya en afirmativo o en negativo para denotar la obligación en el primer caso. Como tú indicas, la frase expresa que las figuras **no** deben aparecer alineadas (obligación de no aparecer así). Si los puntos se otorgan en cualquier caso, la frase debería haber sido

> *son figuras que no necesitan aparecer alineadas para ganar puntos*

Answer (score 0):

Si consideramos la expresión aislada:

> no deben aparecer alineadas

Está claro que afirma que es obligatorio que no aparezcan alineadas.

El problema surge al considerar el resto de la oración. La misma es **ambigua**, porque se puede interpretar de dos maneras:

> (no deben aparecer alineadas) para ganar puntos

Y:

> no (deben aparecer alineadas para ganar puntos)

En la primera interpretación, está diciendo que para ganar puntos es obligatorio que no aparezcan alineadas. En la segunda, que para ganar puntos no es obligatorio que aparezcan alineadas. Notar que en la segunda interpretación, la expresión aislada que mencionamos al principio ya no es una unidad. O sea que el problema no es cómo interpretar “no + deber + infinitivo”, sino en determinar si esa es realmente la estructura de la oración.

Este tipo de ambigüedades es común al expresar reglas en lenguaje natural y para el que las escribe pueden pasar desapercibido que se pueden interpetar de más de una manera. En el caso del juego que mencionas, por lo que cuentas es esperable que se trate de la segunda interpretación: no tendría mucho sentido que se penalice que las figuras especiales aparezcan alineadas cuando en las comunes se premia. Por supuesto que hay maneras más claras de expresarlo, por ejemplo cambiando *deben* por *necesitan*.